# NHibernate.Linq LockMode

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Is it possible to set the LockMode when using NHibernate.Linq? When using ICriteria I can this way:

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>();
criteria.SetLockMode(LockMode.None);
criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("Title", title));
```

Is it possible to build that same query using Nhibernate.Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so... I just grepped through  the [NHibernate.Linq source code](https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Linq/) and [its tests](https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate.Test/Linq/) and found no reference to LockMode.

Comment: Maybe they will add it in the future release.

Answer (score 2):

You can still achieve the lock on entity using Session.Lock(entity,LockMode.read)

Thanks

Comment: I never understood this way of locking. The entity has already been selected and materialized. Someone could have selected it from db before we got a chance to call Session.Lock right?